# git successfully push changes to main repository but still see no changes in the files

Tags: git

I set up a repo on a shared hosting server. I want to use git from now on for pushing my local changes directly to my shared host, but despite the ok message I still see no changes in files:

### ON SHARED HOST (REMOTE SERVER)

Initialize git repo

```
cd public_html/.git
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
```

### ON MY LAPTOP (LOCAL SERVER)

I cloned it the central remote repo on local machine

```
git clone ssh://me@mdomain.ro:15554/home/mydomain/public_html/.git
```

Now I have a working copy of the remote repository
I only have one branch called 'master'. I can see it:

```
git branch
```

I add the remote repository under the name 'origin':

```
git remote add origin ssh://me@mdomain.ro:15554/home/mydomain/public_html/.git
```

I can list the remote repositories:

```
git remote
```

will display: origin
At this stage I have done my work commit my changes again (as above)
Now I push the changes back to the remote server where my main repository is.

```
git push origin master
```

### ON SHARED HOST (REMOTE SERVER)

I managed to make it somehow by converting the remote repository to bare repository:

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

### ON MY LAPTOP (LOCAL SERVER)

I push again the data:

```
git push origin master
```

and got

```
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 663.98 KiB, done.
Total 32 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://me@mdomain.ro:15554/home/mdomain.ropublic_html/.git
   a416e72..bb19005  master -> master
```

However, when accessing my url in browser I still cannot see changes. What is wrong?

Comment: The `git remote add` part isn’t necessary, by the way; `git clone` gets that for you.

Comment: @minitech In my case it was useful to name the remote repository as'origin'. More handy.

Comment: you should consider to configure the remote repository as a bare repo. In order to convert a repo to a bare one you should run: `git config --bool core.bare true`

Comment: Thanks I did this and worked. Good point. See my update. However I see no changes in my website. What could be wrong?

Comment: You can’t just put the bare repository in `public_html`, either (that’s why I didn’t answer) — I *think* it takes hooks, but I’m inexperienced with Git, so maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite clear and indicative that the server cannot update the working tree of the currently checked out branch (`master`).

To fix this, you could look into [how to convert your server's repo to a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare).

Another option (though I highly recommend against this) is to set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` in the server repo's git config to either `ignore` or `warn` or `false`.

If what you're trying to do is to use `git push` as a means to deploy new code on the server, and you need to have a work-tree even with a bare repo, you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667542/380757) answer I posted some time back, which details how to have a separate work-tree checked out on the server and setup a post-receive hook which takes care of updating this worktree from the bare repo.

Comment: Thanks I did this and worked. See my update. However despite the succesful message I see no changes in the files on  website. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Kandinski - I've updated the answer with a possible link to another answer I posted some time back, which I'm guessing is what you're looking for ?

Comment: I  carefully read it so my work tree is public_html and my repo is public_html/.git (correct me if i am wrong). I don't know how to split them up. I have created the public_html/.git/hooks/post-receive on the main remote server. Now locally I run git push origin master which runs ok, no errors but I see no changes on the files on the main remote server. What is still wrong?

Comment: @Kandinski I assume these files are webpages. Do you need them to be in the public_html directory? Then you need to run `git reset --hard HEAD` in the public_html director. You can most likely automate this as a hook, but I don't have any experience with those.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I run the git reset --hard HEAD but I get: fatal - this operation must be run in a work tree. Now where the earth is this work tree as I my work tree should be here?

Comment: @Tuxdude How do you suggest I should split up my work tree and repo to follow the best practice? I can't believe, isn't it my problem a common one?

Comment: @Kandinski - a git's bare repo only needs to contain all the files under the `.git` directory. The first link in my answer should explain how to convert your existing repo into a bare repo. You can think of the work-tree is the list of files checked out corresponding to a branch or a tag or any commit. A bare repo does not have a work-tree of its own. But using a post-receive hook, you can run a command such as `GIT_WORK_TREE=/foo/bar git checkout -f` to update the work-tree at `/foo/bar` on every `git push`, so that the work-tree gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

For a git repo to admit `push` it has to be configured as `bare`.

A bare-repository just contains the version information. The working files are not there. Instead it contains the whole content of the folder `.git`.

You created your repository in the 'server' as non-bare repository so you cannot push. If you have just started just create it again with `git --bare init` but if you already did important changes you need to convert it

Comment: Thanks I did this and worked. See my update. However despite the succesful message I see no changes in the files on  website. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This method is for git self-hosting or sharing host ... (isn't github host or private repo)

First step from git Bash of your win or other OS :

```
git push -u origin master
```

`[origin]` is you `<alias>` remote

In you hosting server (sharing or any Server that support `git` and `SSH`)

```
git log --oneline
```

you see last commit that you pushed from you client git Bash.
for example you see something like this:

```
6d523ed modify last commit
37b624b .gitignore is now working
f1e0413 add *.zip to ignore file
c5r0d74 add .gitignore
4e87i69 Installing
```

> Note: above code was my commit. you commit is differance.

Now you have to using `git reset` for sharing you last commit on you local computer to your public_html or anyplace that you initialized git on your Hosting Server.

```
git reset --hard 6d523ed
```

Note: `6d523ed` is `SHA-1` Last `Commit` which you can see above text.

> Important: I testing almost 100000 way for sharing direct (git bare) from my local computer to remote master (public_html) but it not working...!!!!

It may work in GitHub but other hosting server not working any change without use `reset --hard`